# How to create a Android screenshot with smartphone around

Tags: android, screenshot, smartphone

How can I create a Android screenshot from the smartphone itself and place a smartphone around like you can see it on this page: http://hskampus.de/?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a screenshot by pressing volume down and power button at the same time.

Then you can use the [Android Device Art Generator](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/device-art.html) to generate the device around it.

Comment: this Art Generator is absolutely amazing

Answer (score 0):

[Take a screenshot of the android screen](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/3446798/how-take-screenshot-on-android-phones-tablets/), and then edit it into the smartphone picture, add some effect and you're done.